# Automatically add characters into long number in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to use custom formatting in a cell to apply a formula to change a text string of "01020304" into "01:02:03;04", by adding the colons and semicolons into the string?

I've put together an Excel spreadsheet that will calculate the difference in time between two video timecodes and return the difference as a timecode.

Timecodes must be entered into cells using the format "hh:mm:ss;ff" (hours:minutes:seconds;frames) for the calculation formulae to work.

This means using custom cell formatting of `00":"00":"00";"00` isn't an option, as the cell's content won't change.

So is there a formula I could apply via conditional formatting to automatically change "01020304" to "01:02:03;04" by inserting the colons and semicolons in their proper places, after I enter "01020304"?

A copy of the spreadsheet is in this [Google Drive folder](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gGAmsZvwfXcH2w2WraaggJw5WUsueTci/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114642622308615236787&rtpof=true&sd=true).

The calculation formulae are based on work by [GitHub user cgranier](https://github.com/cgranier/Excel-Timecode).

Comment: `=TEXT(A1,"00\:00\:00\;00")`

Comment: You cannot use custom formatting in Excel to format Text. But you can use formulas as shown by @P.b above.  If you must have the result in the same cell as the source data, you will need a VBA solution.  Otherwise, you'll need a separate data entry area or column.

Comment: Thanks both. P.b's formula does what I need. But I don't know where to begin with VBA, so I've got a lot of learning to do.